# csh alias is not avaliable in non-interactive shell

Tags: git, alias, csh, non-interactive

I work in a linux environment where the user's shell is configured as `csh` by default. I'm writing a `git` `post-receive` hook that should trigger as the user in a non-interactive `csh` shell.

My git hook features the following line. This way I can check if the right versions are configured in the environment.

```
    echo "Versions: git (`git --version`), composer (`composer --version`)"
```

The correct versions are configured in `.cshrc.private` in two ways:

- `setenv`

  ```
  # Add local git to path
  setenv PATH ~/software/git/bin\:$PATH
  ```
- `alias`

  ```
  # Add local composer alias
  alias composer /path/to/composer/composer.phar
  ```

What I notice is that `setenv PATH` works but the **`alias` is not picked up in the script** - leading to the incorrect version to be used in the hook. Replacing it with a symbolic link and PATH entry does work.

What would cause this behavior?

Comment: Does the `post-receive` hook run as the desired user? Does non-interactive csh read `~/.cshrc` (that should be verified)? Does `~/.cshrc` source `~/.cshrc.private`?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. I've tested this before posting by disabling and enabling the `setenv PATH` for git in the user's `~/.cshrc.private`.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? smells exactly like what I am struggling with